# finding the prime numbers of an arraylist with toArray, prints wrong

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist, toarray

I have a method for finding the prime number from a list of numbers using ArrayList and toArray. The majority of the code works, except for the fact that when I'm printing the parameters 1 and 10, it prints 1,2,3,5,7. So it prints the prime numbers between 1 and 10, but it also prints 1. I think the error is in the first or second for-loop, but I'm not sure.

```
public int primtall(int a, int b) {
    ArrayList<Integer> primtallene = new ArrayList<>();
    int primtall = 0;
    int største;
    int minste;
    if(a == b){ 
        primtall = 0;
    }
    else {
        if(a > b) {
            største = a;
            minste = b;
        } 
        else if (a < b){
            minste = a;
            største = b;


        for(int i = minste; i <= største; i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) { 
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {

                primtall = i;
                primtallene.add(primtall);
            }
        }
    }

  }

  Integer[] numrene = new Integer[primtallene.size()];
  numrene = primtallene.toArray(numrene);
  for(Integer nummer : numrene){
      System.out.println("Primtall = " + nummer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Dont mind the last return value, I only added that because BlueJ requires me to.

Can anyone help with identifying the error in the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if I disagree with any of the answers below, but the number 1 is neither prime nor composite.  It should be subject to your prime test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's becuase of the below `for` loop:

```
for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) { 
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

For the first time, `i` will be 1, which would make `j < i` condition return false and hence, control won't go into this for loop.

Due to this, `isPrime` will be true and `1` will get added into the list. To prevent this, you can just check whether `i >= 2` in subsequent `if` condition, e.g.

```
if (isPrime && i >= 2) {
    primtall = i;
    primtallene.add(primtall);
}
```

Also, if you don't want to `return` any value from this method, you can change the return type as `void` and remove `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) { 
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

if `i=1`, (which would be the case when minste=1)the above loop will never be entered and `isPrime = false;` would never be executed. Hence, for i=1 is picked as prime.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with 1, `minste` will be 1 and the code never enters the second `for` loop, and `isPrime` ends up being `true`.

If you already know that 1 shouldn't be printed, you don't need to check it. Instead, you could start the first `for` loop with 2